# redirect_uri blocking ability to make intranet-based application

Tags: intranet, facebook-oauth

I'm working on a intranet-based application that the company I work for will sell that will have the ability to post to Facebook walls as part of a background process.

To authorize, I need to go through the flow (i.e. `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize` with parameters `client_id=1234567890` and `redirect_uri=http://customer-intranet.example.com`)—and it's the second one that's stymieing me, because I can't predict `redirect_uri`, and Facebook seems to be strict about the whole thing being pre-specified in the app.

I'm thinking I need to set up a hosted site that receives the access token from Facebook and then somehow redirects that token back to the customer's intranet site where it can be used.  (And then there's the whole offline access token deprecation thing...)

Am I making things too hard for myself?  Is there a better way to do this?  I've looked over the other authentication flows, and of them, device *might* work, but it's apparently in closed beta.

Comment: Question:Could a requirement be set for the intranet site to be exposed (in a limited way) on the internet using an external facing domain name e.g. partner.example.com which will receive the auth callback from Facebook?

Comment: Yeah, that's the route I'm looking at right now; see my third paragraph.  I didn't want to get into hosting anything, even a small service, for this project if I could avoid it, but it looks like I may have to.

Comment: If all you need is a wall post, you might be able to get away with having the hosted site do the actual post for you too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may consider [Client Side authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) flow or using [JS-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) with [OAuth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/), that way you may easily avoid specifying `redirect_uri` since it may be provided automatically by JS-SDK (or you may use current URL `window.location` as shown in documentatio  of Client Side auth flow).

**Notes:**

While this may help you to avoid usage of `redirect_uri` actual problem is a bit deeper...

Usage of `redirect_uri` will make such flow hard to implement not only due to inability to predict it, but due to requirement that `redirect_uri` should be located within **App Domain**, same goes for usage of JS-SDK.

[image: Application Settings screenshot]

So generally you will be required to place the domain name of `redirect_uri` / *URL Application Running on* in the application settings, which is nasty in case of many clients/domains.

You may implement auth flow by using separate (publicly accessible) host but it's good to ask yourself a couple of question before doing so:

1. Who will be responsible for that host and what will happen with all your clients if something going wrong with that host for auth only.

   - It's additional dependency which is better to avoid.
2. Will you be albe to provide domains for all of your clients in application settings?

   - This may lead to violation of platform policies on data transfer to third parties (consult a company lawyer before doing so)
3. Are you required to use single Application for all your clients?

   - If not you better instruct clients to set-up application and configure your application/code with credentials they got.

**Summarizing stuff:**
You can create separate application for every client or instruct client to set-up application as part of install/set-up process for you application. Later you may use Client Side authentication flow to create generic code that will work for every client (this is possible with Server Side flow too, but will require some additional work and with JS-SDK `FB.login` it may be a drop-in functionality without any additional work).

Comment: That's about as complete an investigation of the issue as I imagine I'm going to get.  Some of it I already knew, but it's still useful.  I'll give you the bounty unless someone comes out with a miracle cure in the next two days.  Thanks!